# What would make a groke's metabolism endothermic in the thermodynamic sense?

Tags: fantasy-races, temperature

[This](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/could-a-life-form-evolve-an-organ-for-generating-temperatures-less-than-a-degree) recent question got me thinking about a creature concept I've tentatively named after everyone's favourite Moomins character, [the Groke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Groke). In particular, the creature concept is based on her below-freezing body temperature.

So, this creature, which may or may not look like a large purple bed-sheet ghost, has a metabolism that has a highly endothermic component, which leads my grokes to hunt living beings for their body heat as much as the meat. They do not necessarily maintain this body heat when they aren't freezing a creature to death.

What I'm stumped on is, just what sort of a metabolic pathway is going on here? Is this even feasible?

Comment: Something is wrong here: if you can keep your body at below freezing temperature, why hunting when you can use environmental temperature already?

Comment: @L.Dutch maybe they live in an environment where the temperature is below body heat, or just that a living creature contains more thermal energy than is easy to obtain from air (I'd have to crunch the numbers on that one)

Comment: @HAEM The Groke is not my favourite Moomins character.  The only Moomins story I ever read was "The Invisible Child" according to this question and answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/210683/childrens-anthology-with-the-first-chapter-of-the-hobbit-and-a-moomintroll-story and I remember very little about it.  Many people on this board and others throughout the world have no knowledge of the Moomins, so saying that the Groke is "everyone's" favorite is clearly inaccurate.

Comment: @HAEM then it would probably move south, or to somewhere volcanic. Murdersnacking is risky and a lot of effort, and starts to seem a bit silly when you could go somewhere which has a free all-you-can-eat buffet every day (and for somewhere with the right geology, every night, too).

Comment: @StarfishPrime Thing is, polar bears also subsist on murdersnacking in a climate where moving south would be the smart solution. Evolution doesn't do what's smart, it does what's sufficient.

Comment: @HAEM they are somewhere with a large supply of food, and little competition, Anywhere else they go either has less food, more competition, or both. Are you proposing a world _already_ filled with thermovores, such that the groke is forced to live somewhere freezing cold because that's the only unexploited niche to expand into?

Comment: @StarfishPrime Okay, so maybe it's the temperate to arctic grokes that hunt agressively, although all of them would still be semi-carnivorous.

Comment: Perhaps the reason they're so cold is because they eat [the things from this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/148108/62341).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They don’t need heat to gain energy from it. They need heat to survive the massively endothermic process of laying down their energy stores.

The Grokes evolved in a high temperature environment where food occasionally showed up in large quantities and was scarce the rest of the time. As a response they evolved a highly sophisticated, highly efficient, highly energy dense ‘fat’ analogue that uses a series of catalyst enabled endothermic reactions to ‘lock in’ as much of that energy as possible to save for later.

In their natural habitat these reactions aren’t an issue. The Groke would simply be quite cool just after feeding.

Here, however, it’s too cool. A freshly fed Groke *needs* to find a good heat source to keep itself warm while it’s body lays down it’s ‘fat’ stores. This means Grokes hunt not only for food, but for food *and* heat.

Now a sensible Groke will regulate its food intake, eating little and often and simply presenting as a cool bed sheet ghost rather than a freezing funereal shroud of death. Even more sensible Grokes have handy heat sources nearby and do their best *not* to kill them, as only a fool kills a still warm moomin.

Of course, once a Groke has fed it can go for a long, long time (at a more reasonable temperature) without needing extra food, or burn up those energy stores incredibly quickly (and hotly) by reversing the process. They can also survive up to quite extreme heats (which remind them of home).